# Google Map Api: creating mutliple key from single account to avoid usage limit

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using javascript google map api to show maps to the user. previously it was working fine but suddenly i am getting error in the console as "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys". it means i have to include key while loading javascript map api library. google have limit of 25000 maps load per day for javascript map api.

My question is can i create multiple key from single google account to increase the google map api limit?? or if it is not possible then can i create multiple keys by using multiple google account and use these keys to increase google map limit.

Thanks,

Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: It's not a good solution (even not legal). If you have the request volume, you can use the Standard Plan Pricing calculator https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#sup_3

Comment: And you will have more than 25 000 maps loaded per day? I think this is not the right forum for trying to find ways about how to avoid terms of usage ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even try it.

I think Google is able to track the URL from which page the request comes from and your page will be blocked. Maybe even your google account.

Oh. And is is against the terms of usage ;)